# Covert Wordpress Blogname into JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, javascript

Here is the blogname in php `<?php $blog_title = get_bloginfo('name'); ?>`
I want to convert it to javascript. The file I want the blog name is in a .js file so I cant create the variable with php.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732178/wordpress-php-functions-inside-ajax-requests-not-working-alternative#answer-9732618).

Comment: I looked at it but I don't understand how to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)

```
function set_js_var() {
  $translation_array = array( 'blog_name' => get_bloginfo('name') );
  wp_localize_script( 'jquery', 'my_data', $translation_array );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','set_js_var');
```

If you look at the source of the page you will see something like:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var my_data = {"blog_name":"WordPress 3.5.1 Release"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

That is your Javascript variable.

You have to "register" that on some existing Javascript slug. That is, some slug you've already used to register a script. That is why I used `jquery`, which is the slug used by WordPress to load its bundled `jQuery` library.